# Use of Complex (curly) Syntax in external file

Tags: php, sql, string-interpolation

I am having a problem with getting an sql query to interpolate as I would want, and would be grateful for some help please.

Within the manual page for [pg_query_params](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php),there is a code example for pg_query() passing  a variable using curly braces. This appeared to be exactly what I need for my task. So, my code is as follows:

```
$fh = fopen('/home/www/KPI-Summary.sql',"r")
      or die("Problem opening SQL file.\n");
$dbh = pg_connect("$connect")
      or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$j = 0;
while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
    $tmp[$j] = array();                         // Initialise temporary storage.
    $result = pg_query($dbh, $line);            // process the line read.
    if (!$result) { echo "Error: query did not execute"; }
...
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {      // Read sql result.
        $tmp[$j][2][] = $row;
        }
    $j++;
    }
fclose($fh);
```

The sql file contains several queries, one per line, like this:

```
SELECT count(*) from table WHERE value=0 AND msgid='{$arg[1]}';
```

However, currently, my variable is not being replaced by the contents -- and therefore although the query runs OK, it is returning zero rows. What do I need to do in order to get the expected result? **(Note: each sql line varies, and the query parameters are not constant -- hence using variable(s) within the sql file.)**

Comment: When you read contents of a file with `fopen()/fgets()`, PHP won't interpret the contents as PHP (so no variables will be unpacked). You'll just get a string with the contents "as is". You shouldn't put variables inside your queries like that anyway since it leaves you open to SQL injections. There are edge cases where even escaping the values aren't enough. Use [prepared statements with placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) instead. If you can't do that in the way you have written the code now, then consider rethinking your architecture.

Comment: Thanks for reminder about sql injection. It this case however, it is not a risk, since there is no tainted data. The WHERE clause includes (but is not limited to) an auto-generated placeholder (eg. WHERE mgsid=<value> AND foo>0). Since the query WHERE clause varies, I can't see how I can prepare the query, or pass parameters...

Comment: @PaulT. No - the single quotes are a required part of a valid SQL query (and doesn't affect interpolation anyway).

Comment: @Phil ... Yes, you're right, I might have fooled myself with the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have *a* solution (although it might not be the *correct* approach).
This works -- but it needs polish I think. Suggestions regarding a better regexp would be very much appreciated.

```
$bar = 'VALUE-A';         // Can we replace simple variable names?
$arg[1] = 'VALUE-B';      // What about an array, such as $arg[1]?

function interpolate($matches){
        global $bar;
        global $arg;
        if ($matches[2]) {
                $i = isset(${$matches[1]}[$matches[2]]) ? ${$matches[1]}[$matches[2]] : 'UNDEF';
                } else {
                $i = isset(${$matches[1]}) ? ${$matches[1]} : 'UNDEF';
                }
        return $i;
        }

$fh = fopen('/home/www/file.sql',"r") or die("Failed.\n");
while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
...
        $line = preg_replace_callback('|\{\$([a-z]+)\[*(\d*)\]*}|i', "interpolate", $line);
        echo $line;       // and continue with rest of code as above.
        }
fclose($fh);
```

(Of course, the solution suggests that the question title is completely wrong. Is there any way to edit this?)

Comment: I hope you work alone, your indentation style would get you violently assaulted in the hallways here lol

Answer (score -1):

did you use pg_escape_string?

```
$arg[1] = pg_escape_string($arg[1]);
$line="SELECT count(*) from table WHERE value=0 AND msgid='{$arg[1]}';";
```

Comment: $arg[1] is an alphanumeric string of a dozen chars. nothing to escape. M.Eriksson has explain the 'why'. I need to find an alternative that will work. Have tried file_get_contents, but that's no good either.